# How to change Html of psuedo elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently making a web application that behaves identically to the link below. My goal is to make it so when a slider is clicked, the psuedo element of .slider:before (The white part that slides across) has an image I want to add in the middle of it and text (very small). So before, nothing in the white psuedo element part. Just like the example from w3schools that's similar. But when its clicked a capital A (for example) appears.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 34px;
    }

    .switch input {display:none;}

    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }

    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 26px;
      width: 26px;
      left: 4px;
      bottom: 4px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }

    input:checked + .slider {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }

    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
      transform: translateX(26px);
    }

    /* Rounded sliders */
    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label><br><br>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't modify a pseudo element directly via javascript. What you can do is add a class to the element on click and create a css rule to generate the desired behavior.

Comment: Didn't downvote. Why can you use the `:after` for that with `content: 'whatever';` and make it absolute positioned?

Comment: Well the issue with the rule is that these are many dynamically created sliders. All with the same class and pseudo element. Just individually, I wanted to make it so when one is clicked, that specific one is has an A for example in the white part of its slider.

Comment: @Will So you're saying that it wouldn't be the same text for each slider? For that you can add a special attribute like `<label class="switch" data-caption="AA">` and then select that attribute as the test that will be displayed using `.slider:before { content: attr(data-caption); }`

Comment: Okay. Well I currently have an image placed inside the content via url. Could you somehow make it vertically center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change the CSS:
Change this:

```css
input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

To this:

```css
input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
    content: "A"; //Or something else
}
```

Comment: That is the fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to bru02's answer, you can use css `attr()` function to get dynamic content on your pseudo selectors. For that, just add a data-title (or anything else) to the slider element and use `content: attr(data-title)` to the  css rule.

Looks like this (with flex for centering):

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  color: white;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
  content: attr(data-label); /* <-- where the magic happens*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #444;
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" data-label="A"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" data-label="B"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" data-label="C"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" data-label="D"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" data-label="E"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to have a url and attr in the content?

Comment: Not a clickable url, but you can put more than one attr in the content, like: `content: attr(data-label) '/' attr(data-url);`

Comment: Okay thanks. one more thing, any idea on how you could possibly style the content ? Like making it a bit from the top etc. Thanks alot.

Comment: The content has some styling limitations. You can position it via flex, like I did, and use `color`, etc. But those stylings are actually being applied to the pseudo element.

Comment: Okay. Well I currently have an image placed inside the content via url. Didn't know if I could make it center.